# Windows command line renaming files in subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I didn't find so far a similar question, so I try to explain the problem:

I have large number of files that are in subfolders inside `"C:\images"`
I have a list of names in two columns, so that 1st column is old filename and 2nd is a new filename. I want to change that list into a batch file.
Names are pretty unique so I want to make batch file - so that will be one command for every file to be renamed.

```
RENAME "C:\images\768e11ab.jpg" "4ca5d042.jpg"
RENAME "C:\images\5402c708.jpg" "b802820b.jpg"
RENAME "C:\images\1c039e0e.jpg" "80ce9797.jpg"
etc...
```

It is rather simple, only, files are scattered across subfolders. Is there any way to make a command so it will look for that specific file in all subfolders in `"C:\images"` and rename it.
Following some similar questions tried this, with no result:

```
for /r "C:\images\" "%%~G" (768e11ab.jpg) do "4ca5d042.jpg"
```

Also, tried to use some renaming application for this but they freeze when I try to rename big list of files, so I would avoid them and use batch file. Also, I would like to use this way where there is one line in batch file for every file because it is simpler for me to use it (and change it later). I appreciate your help.

Comment: so you have the files in different subfolders; you have the file names, but not their location. Right? (Just want to clarify, because your code and your text don't agree on that)

Comment: How does your list file look like? How are the columns separated? What is the scale of  your large number? You could build a lookup table from your list, iterate the files and if there is an entry in the table rename the file.

Comment: To find out how to use a command, open a Command Prompt window and enter, `command /?`. For example, to see the usage information for the `for` command, use `for /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Approach the problem from the other side. Instead of looping over the image files, loop over the text file.

Assuming your textfile to be something like

```
"768e11ab.jpg" "4ca5d042.jpg"
"5402c708.jpg" "b802820b.jpg"
"1c039e0e.jpg" "80ce9797.jpg"
```

Then the code could look like:

```
@echo off
REM read each line; %%A is the first column, %%B is the second one
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (list.txt) do (
  REM search the image file %%A
  for /R "C:\Images\" %%C in ("%%~A") do (
    REM %%C now holds the full path of %%A
    ECHO ren "%%~C" "%%B~%%~xC"
  )
)
```

If your list looks different, the tokens and perhaps the delims for the `for /f` loop have to be adapted.

NOTE: the `ren` command is just echoed for security reasons. Once you verified it does exactly what you want, remove the `ECHO` to enable the * ren` command.